# Emergency Travel Document through Narita

Tags: delta-air-lines

I will be traveling from Albany, NY to Manila via Delta airlines. I will be traveling on Philippines Emergency Travel Documents. I have heard rumors that you cant travel through Narita with these. I dont see what the issue will be if I have a immediate connecting flight. I will not be leaving Terminal 1. Anyone have any info on this? Thanks

Comment: I must be too tired to be on the internet ... I keep reading the title of this question as "... through Narnia".

Comment: Are you sure you’re not confusing this with temporary visit permits or shore leave? I

Answer (score 2):

You can travel, but your connecting flight must leave on the same calendar day and you cannot leave the international transit area. If you connect instead through Haneda you can remain up to 72 hours.

Connecting landside through Japan requires obtaining a shore pass from immigration, and that requires an actual passport.

Timatic states:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Tokyo (HND) or Osaka (KIX) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 72 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a passport and a confirmed onward ticket to a third country within 72 hours can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar day.